# Can't connect to a Debian on CHIP from Macbook

Tags: linux, networking, mac, arm

I've got a weird problem I have no idea how to fix.
I have an old CHIP computer. It's a single board computer similar to Raspberry Pi. It runs on ARMv7 CPU and has RTL8723BS WiFi chip.

Originally it had Debian 8 OS. The computer itself is very old - produced about 7-8 years ago. The manufacturer has bankrupted since then so whole project isn't maintained anymore.

Recently I decided to use it as a print server and first thing I did - upgraded to Debian 12. I did it gradually (8 -> 9 -> ... -> 12) and after upgrade to Debian 9 weird problem has appeared. I can't connect to it from Macbook. From any other devices (Android, Windows, Linux) it works with no problem.

When I run `tcpdump` on CHIP I see following:

```
14:31:07.098962 ARP, Request who-has chip.home (7c:c7:09:e3:48:16 (oui Unknown)) tell Universe.home, length 28
14:31:07.099088 ARP, Reply chip.home is-at 7c:c7:09:e3:48:16 (oui Unknown), length 28
14:31:07.099489 IP Universe.home.64773 > chip.home.ssh: Flags [S], seq 3641540390, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 4128150543 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
14:31:07.099869 IP chip.home.ssh > Universe.home.64773: Flags [S.], seq 1651611513, ack 3641540391, win 28960, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 145561 ecr 4128150543,nop,wscale 6], length 0
14:31:08.053134 IP Universe.home.64773 > chip.home.ssh: Flags [S], seq 3641540390, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 4128151543 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
14:31:08.053344 IP chip.home.ssh > Universe.home.64773: Flags [S.], seq 1651611513, ack 3641540391, win 28960, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 145751 ecr 4128150543,nop,wscale 6], length 0
14:31:08.053162 ARP, Request who-has chip.home (7c:c7:09:e3:48:16 (oui Unknown)) tell Universe.home, length 28
14:31:08.053562 ARP, Reply chip.home is-at 7c:c7:09:e3:48:16 (oui Unknown), length 28
14:31:09.048597 IP chip.home.ssh > Universe.home.64773: Flags [S.], seq 1651611513, ack 3641540391, win 28960, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 145951 ecr 4128150543,nop,wscale 6], length 0
14:31:09.054381 IP Universe.home.64773 > chip.home.ssh: Flags [S], seq 3641540390, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 4128152544 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
14:31:09.054520 IP chip.home.ssh > Universe.home.64773: Flags [S.], seq 1651611513, ack 3641540391, win 28960, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 145952 ecr 4128150543,nop,wscale 6], length 0
14:31:09.054915 ARP, Request who-has chip.home (7c:c7:09:e3:48:16 (oui Unknown)) tell Universe.home, length 28
14:31:09.055083 ARP, Reply chip.home is-at 7c:c7:09:e3:48:16 (oui Unknown), length 28
14:31:11.053592 IP chip.home.ssh > Universe.home.64773: Flags [S.], seq 1651611513, ack 3641540391, win 28960, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 146352 ecr 4128150543,nop,wscale 6], length 0
14:31:11.058116 ARP, Request who-has chip.home tell Universe.home, length 28
14:31:11.058242 ARP, Reply chip.home is-at 7c:c7:09:e3:48:16 (oui Unknown), length 28
14:31:12.058155 ARP, Request who-has chip.home tell Universe.home, length 28
14:31:12.058259 ARP, Reply chip.home is-at 7c:c7:09:e3:48:16 (oui Unknown), length 28
14:31:14.164125 ARP, Request who-has chip.home tell Universe.home, length 28
14:31:14.164248 ARP, Reply chip.home is-at 7c:c7:09:e3:48:16 (oui Unknown), length 28
14:31:15.053597 IP chip.home.ssh > Universe.home.64773: Flags [S.], seq 1651611513, ack 3641540391, win 28960, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 147152 ecr 4128150543,nop,wscale 6], length 0
14:31:18.059133 ARP, Request who-has chip.home tell Universe.home, length 28
14:31:18.059295 ARP, Reply chip.home is-at 7c:c7:09:e3:48:16 (oui Unknown), length 28
14:31:23.053598 IP chip.home.ssh > Universe.home.64773: Flags [S.], seq 1651611513, ack 3641540391, win 28960, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 148752 ecr 4128150543,nop,wscale 6], length 0
14:31:28.063530 ARP, Request who-has Universe.home tell chip.home, length 28
14:31:29.063528 ARP, Request who-has Universe.home tell chip.home, length 28
14:31:30.063554 ARP, Request who-has Universe.home tell chip.home, length 28
```

At the same time on Macbook I see:

```
14:33:55.578476 ARP, Request who-has chip.home (7c:c7:09:e3:48:16 (oui Unknown)) tell universe.home, length 28
14:33:55.578598 IP universe.home.64822 > chip.home.ssh: Flags [S], seq 670887126, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 2897939957 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
14:33:56.578766 ARP, Request who-has chip.home (7c:c7:09:e3:48:16 (oui Unknown)) tell universe.home, length 28
14:33:56.578956 IP universe.home.64822 > chip.home.ssh: Flags [S], seq 670887126, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 2897940958 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
14:33:57.579178 ARP, Request who-has chip.home (7c:c7:09:e3:48:16 (oui Unknown)) tell universe.home, length 28
14:33:57.579380 IP universe.home.64822 > chip.home.ssh: Flags [S], seq 670887126, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 2897941958 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
14:33:58.579209 ARP, Request who-has chip.home tell universe.home, length 28
```

It seems the Macbook doesn't see reply from CHIP. But I don't understand why would
Macbook not seeing what others see and why would it happen after upgrade from Debian 8.
Any idea?